# What is ' chicken garlic chicken '

Tags: chicken, garlic

I was at a Brewers Fayre pub and saw this on the menu (pictured) 
When it arrived it was an egg on top of a garlic and breadcrumb chicken breast. Why call it chicken garlic chicken? The waitress didn't react in the slightest to the name, and it's still on the menu now 
Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: Maybe its cause the egg is from a chicken, so you have the chicken cutlet with garlic and a pre-fetus of a chicken in the fried egg? Or a typo they've been rolling with? You could just ask the waitress the next time you're there.

Comment: @Batman ah yes, hadn't thought of that, smart idea!

Comment: Perhaps they feed the chickens garlic, too...

Comment: I've posted my thoughts but I'm afraid this may be something the pub only knows. :)

Comment: Yes I think you might be right, still your answer makes a lot of sense, I'll ask next time and update you all!

Comment: Please do! I'd love to know the reason!

Comment: Maybe it was named by "Bond James Bond" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purely conjecture but...

You've heard of chicken fried steak... right?
We also have [chicken fried chicken](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2015/07/chicken-fried-chicken-with-cream-gravy-recipe.html)... which is chicken prepared in the same way as chicken fried steak. It's different than "fried chicken " because it's a boneless (often pounded) piece of breast meat.

It's amusingly recursive.

So, based on the description on the menu, it sounds like a version of chicken fried chicken but with lots of garlic, so maybe they decided to replace the "scary" word, "fried" with the delicious word "garlic".

Unfortunately this conjecture falls apart somewhat since chicken fried chicken is a staple of the southern US and the menu seems to be from a pub in England somewhere.